# Animating arc to horizontal line with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to animate an arc into a horizontal line and am not sure if this is possible and what is the best way to go about it. I'm drawing an arc using a path generator:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(function(d){ return d.outerRadius; })
  .innerRadius(function(d){ return d.outerRadius*0.6; })
  .startAngle(function(d){ return d.startAngle; })
  .endAngle(function(d){ return d.endAngle; });
```

Then I am reading json data in and appending the arcs using pie layout:

```
var donut = d3.layout.pie();
var paths = arcs.selectAll("path").data(donut(json));
  paths.enter().append("path")
  .on("click", anim)
  .attr("d", arc).transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("d", tweenPie);
```

When the path is clicked on I want to be able to animate the arc to open up and flatten out to a horizontal line. How can I do this? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: I would use a SVG editor, and import an arc you're interested in. Then, I would manually straighten it, and see, what values changed and how - then I'd figure the transition between a curved arc and a straight line corresponding to it. (Your line has to be an arc too, to be able to perform transition, I think)

Answer (score 3):

an arc opening into a line is like an arc's inner and outer radii growing together, and the end angle separating from the start angle to maintain the same arc length.

first, you know the length of your arc (radius times radians between start and end)

then increase the radius and decrease the distance between start and end so that the arc length remains constant. remember to move the origin of the arc as well to compensate for the growing radii.

as the radius approaches a really large value, the radians between start and end will shrink until there's little or no difference, at which point you'll have a line.